# How to find the interval $[a,b]$ on which fixed-point iteration will converge of a given function $f(x)$?

Tags: numerical-methods

> **Theorem 1**
>   If $g \in [a,b]$ and $g(x) \in [a,b] \forall x \in [a,b]$, then $g$ has a fixed point in $[a,b].$
>   If in addition, $g'(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$ and a positive constant $k < 1$ exists with 
>   $$|g'(x)| \leq k, \text{ for all } \in (a, b)$$ 
>   then the fixed point in $[a,b] is unique.
>
> **Fixed-point Theorem**
>   Let $g \in C[a,b]$ be such that $g(x) \in [a,b]$, for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Suppose, in addition, that $g'$ exists on $(a,b)$ and that a constant $0 < k < 1$ exists with 
>   $$|g'(x)| \leq k, \text{ for all } x \in (a, b)$$
>   Then, for any number $p_0$ in $[a,b]$, the sequence defined by 
>   $$p_n = g(p_{n-1}), n \geq 1$$ 
>   converges to the unique fixed-point in $[a,b]$

These are two theorems that I have learned, and I'm having a hard time with this problem:

> Given a function $f(x)$, how can we find the interval $[a,b]$ on which fixed-point iteration will converge?

Besides guess and check, I couldn't find any other way to solve this problem. I tried to link the above theorems, but it involves two variables, so I have a feeling it can't be solved algebraically. I wonder is there a general way to find the interval of convergence rather trial and error? Thank you.

Comment: Well, any interval stable by $f$ and such that $|f'|\le k$ on this interval with $k<1$ (that is what the theorem tells you, no?). If $f(x)=(x+3/x)/2$ for example, $f'(x)=(1-3/x^2)/2$ hence any closed interval included in $(1,+\infty)$ will do.

Comment: In general, the "basin of convergence" for an iteration method like Newton-Raphson has a *fractal* boundary. See [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=DyykEZo4fwUC&pg=PA461) for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iteration converges for any starting point in an interval stable by $f$ and such that $|f'|\leqslant k$ on this interval, with $k<1$ (this is a mere rephrasing of the theorem). If $f(x)=(x+3/x)/2$ for example, $f'(x)=(1-3/x^2)/2$ hence any closed interval included in $(1,+\infty)$ will do.

Comment: Your condition is sufficient but not necessary.  In your example,  the actual basin of attraction is $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Sure. The interval $(1,+\infty)$ is the one the general theorem the OP is interested in provides. By the way, what you call *my condition* is hardly mine (as I indicate in my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the continuous function $f: {\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$ has an attracting fixed point $p$.  Its immediate basin of attraction (i.e. the maximal interval $J$ such that iteration of $f$ starting at any point in $J$ converges to $p$) must be an open interval $(a,b)$ (infinite intervals allowed).  If $a$ is finite, $f(a)$ must be either $a$ or $b$,
and similarly for $f(b)$. The possibilities are as follows:

1) $a = -\infty$, $b = \infty$

2) One of $a$ and $b$ is a (non-attracting) fixed point, the other is infinite.

3) Both $a$ and $b$ are (non-attracting) fixed points.

4) $a$ is a (non-attracting) fixed point and $f(b) = a$

5) $b$ is a (non-attracting) fixed point and $f(a) = b$

6) $a$ and $b$ form a 2-cycle: $f(a) = b$, $f(b) = a$.

To tell which case you are in, find the non-attracting fixed points of $f$, the points mapped to those, and the 2-cycles.  Note that $(a,b)$ can't contain any of those.

Comment: In what book can I find this precise theorem? Thanks.

Comment: As above, I want to know where I can reference this.