# Finding the fixed point and the suitable range

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

I have to find the fixed point of x$^3$-x$^2$-1=0.Then x=(1/x$^2$)+1 where I chose g(x)=(1/x$^2$)+1 .Then I tried to find a fixed point for g(x).Since I don't know the range of x,I chose x$\in$[1.3,1.6] as the suitable range because in this range 1.3

My question is my chosen range a suitable one?
I wrote a python program to find the fixed point and it found the fixed point 1.47 in just 13 iterations.Why do I get from the program 13 and from calculation 62?

```
def fixedPoint(f,epsilon):

    guess=1.3
    count=0
    p=f(guess)


    while abs(p- guess)>=epsilon:

        guess=p
        p=f(guess)
        count+=1
        print guess

    return "The fixed point is "+str(round(guess,2))+"  and it took "+str(count)+" iterations"

def f(x):

    k=(1/x**2)+1
    return k
```

Comment: Where 62 comes from?

Comment: Well for some reason I couldn't type the sentence after "in this range 1.3<g(x)<1.6 and |g'(x)|<2/1.3$^3$ and I can chose k=2/1.3$^3$,  0<k<1.
With this k I found the minimum required no.of terms by (k^n/1-k)|P1-P0|,P(n)=g(Pn-1)which gave me minimum no.of terms as 62.

"

Comment: My g(x)=(1/x^2)+1 **not** 1/(x^2+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used an **upper bound** on the absolute value of the derivative to find an **upper bound** on the number of iterations required for the desired precision.

The Mean Value Theorem says that if $x_n$ is the $n$-th estimate, and $r$ is the root, then $|x_{n+1}-r|$ is equal to $|x_n-r|$ times the absolute value of $g'(x)$ **somewhere** between $x_n$ and $r$.

It is true that the derivative has absolute value $\lt \frac{2}{(1.3)^3}$. But that only gives us an upper bound on the "next" error in terms of the previous error.

Furthermore, as $x_n$ gets close to $r$, say around $1.4$ or closer, the relevant derivative has significantly smaller absolute value than your $k$.

A further **huge** factor in this case is that the derivative is negative. That means that estimates alternate between being too small and being too big. When $x_n\gt r$, the derivative has significantly smaller absolute value than your estimate $k$.

Even at the beginning, the convergence rate is faster than the one predicted from the pessimistic estimate of the derivative, particularly since half the time $x_n\gt r$.  After a while, the disparity, for $x_n\lt r$,  gets greater.

**Remark:** You know the root $r$ to high precision. It might be informative to modify the program so that at each stage it prints out $\frac{x_{n+1}-r}{x_n-r}$. That way, you can make a comparison between the upper bound $\frac{2}{(1.3)^3}$ on the ratio, and the actual ratio. Even not very large differences, under repeated compounding, can result in much quicker convergence than the one predicted from the upper bound.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.Is the interval I have chosen is correct?And what is meant by " As we get reasonably close to the root, the derivative has significantly smaller absolute value than your k. "

Comment: There are two factors, I only mentioned one, so will add to the post. Let $r$ be the root, about $1.47$. The Mean Value Theorem says that the "next" error is equal to the current error times the derivative somewhere **between** $x_n$ and $r$. You are using the derivative at $1.3$ as an upper bound on the derivative "somewhere between." That is safe, but pessimistic. Furthermore, when $x_n$ is say something like $1.43$, the absolute value of the derivative is actually less than $\frac{2}{(1.43)^3}$, a fair bit better than $\frac{2}{(1.3)^3}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: You are welcome. You might consider doing the calculation suggested in the remark. It will tell you exactly what is going on. It is quite frequent that error estimates, for fixed point iteration, or numerical integration, or approximation by Taylor polynomials, give "pessimistic" estimates that are some distance from the truth. Your calculation **guaranteed** that no more than $62$ steps would be needed, but it did not imply that one would need that many.

Comment: As I get to  know r only at the end how can I make it to print out $\frac{x_{n+1}-r}{x_n-r}$ at **each stage**

Comment: Two answers: (1) I was thinking of it as a tool to find out what went on. You do **now** know $r$ to high accuracy. So you can write a program that does it, and from scanning the numbers learn how the gains in accuracy actually behaved. (2) You can compare $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}$ and $x_{n+1}-x_n$ on the fly, without knowing $r$. This comes fairly close to measuring gains in accuracy, and is used in many real world programs.

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$x = g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2} +1$$

By the way, we could just as well choose a different $g(x)$ and some can be better than others.

If we plot this, it shows:

[image]

For a starting value of $x=1.3$, the fixed point should result in:

$$x = 1.46557137542.$$

As to when it works, see these [*Fixed Point Iteration*](http://bruce-shapiro.com/math481A/notes/9-fixed-point.pdf) notes, but here is a summary:

- Let $\alpha$ be the root of the equation $x = g(x)$.
- The iteration is $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$.
- We can derive that $(x_{n+1} - \alpha) \approx g'(\alpha)(x_n - \alpha)$
- The iteration converges if $|g'(\alpha)| < 1$, and diverges if $|g'(\alpha)|>1$.
- The rare case $g(\alpha)=1$ can correspond either to very slow convergence or to very slow divergence.
- See Thm. 9.4 in the notes.
- See [How to find the interval $[a,b]$ on which fixed-point iteration will converge of a given function $f(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69472/how-to-find-the-interval-a-b-on-which-fixed-point-iteration-will-converge-of) for guidance on what that range is.

Comment: Needs a TU! All that nice work - +1