# Given $y_0\in(0,b)$ and $y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}y_k(3-y_k^2)$ converges. Find $b$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

Given $y_0\in(0,b)$ and $y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}y_k(3-y_k^2)$ converges to $1$. Find $b$.

I know the sequence converges quadratically. But I have no idea how to find $b$.

Comment: Replace  $y_k,y_{k+1}$ in the equation by by the limit, say, $L$. Solve for $L$. Examine  then what happens when you start with various values of $y_0$.

Comment: @uniquesolution $L$ you are referring are the fixed points. But I want the interval of starting values which converges to $1$. Of course you can do it numerically using mathematical software but it is not what I want.

Comment: Show me what can you do numerically, please.

Comment: try $y_0 = 10.$ What happens?

Comment: and then try $y_0=1/10$. What happens?

Comment: @uniquesolution Believe it or not, $b=sqrt(3)$

Comment: So you are saying $y_0$ can be any number in $(0,\sqrt{3})$ and the limit will be $1$???

Comment: @uniquesolution yes

Comment: What does the sequence converge to when $y_0=2$? It's *not* $1$.

Comment: @Marconius Looks like it does not converge. My question is to find $b$ such that it converges.

Comment: If $y_k=-1$ then $y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}(-1)(3-(-1)^2)=-1$, so $-1$ is a fixed point. With $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x(3-x^2)=\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}x^3$ then $g'(x)=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3}{2}x^2 \implies g'(-1)=0 \implies |g'(-1)|<1$ so $x_0=-1$ is an *attractive* fixed point (just like $1$ is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x(3-x^2)$.

Graphical analysis tells us that $f$ sends $(0,1]$ to $(0,1]$ and all points in $(0,1]$ converge to $1$ under iteration of $f$.

Graphical analysis also tells us that $f$ sends $[1,\sqrt3)$ to $(0,1]$.

Thus, the interval you seek is $(0,\sqrt3)$ because it is the largest interval containing the fixed point $1$ that is mapped into itself (or into $(0,1]$). This interval is called the *immediate basin of attraction* of the fixed point $1$.

$\qquad$[image]

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/69482/589.

Comment: Thank you it really helps.