# calculating log

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

how do I solve the following problem:
given `log(x) for x=310,320,330,340,350 and 360 as 2.4913,2.5051,5.5185,2.5440 and 2.5563 find the value of log 337.5`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An alternative way to calculate log(x)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75074/an-alternative-way-to-calculate-logx?rq=1)

Comment: @KingDuken can you explain how is it so?

Comment: Linear approximation claims $f (x) - f(a) \approx f'(a)(x-a) $ so $340 - \log (337.5) \approx \frac {1}{337.5\ln 10}(340 - 337.5) $

Comment: Can't you plot a graph of the values you have and then interpolate the value for 337.5 ?  This would use all the values you have been given, so you should get a 'good feel' for the curve of the graph in that region so you'll have a better approximation.  At what level is the answer expected?

Comment: how do you calculate ln10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just playing around with the numbers, we get that the geometric mean of 310, 330, 340, 350, 360 (and leaving out 320) is about 337.55536830584776.  Thus, $\log 337.5$ is roughly the arithmetic mean of their given logs, or 2.5283.

Of course, we can do a lot better with various products of the $x$ values (and the associated linear combination of the logs), but that's close enough to be correct to 4 significant figures (the true value is about 2.5282737771670436).

Comment: +1.  I assume by "various products" you meant "various powers"; I followed up on that suggestion in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Mnemonic's discussion, just two of the five provided log values are needed.  We have

$$
320 = 2^6 \times 5
$$

and

$$
360 = 2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5
$$

and

$$
337.5 = 2^{-1} \times 3^3 \times 5^2
$$

and of course

$$
10 = 2 \times 5
$$

This gives us

$$
337.5 = \frac{360^{3/2}\times 10^{17/10}}{320^{6/5}}
$$

Since $\log 10 = 1$, we get

$$
\log 337.5 = \frac{3}{2} \log 360 + \frac{17}{10} - \frac{6}{5} \log 320
$$

which is as accurate as the log values we have.  With the log values as given, we obtain

$$
\log 337.5 \doteq 1.5 \times 2.5563 + 1.7 - 1.2 \times 2.5051 \doteq 2.5283
$$

the same answer as obtained by Mnemonic.  However, although $\log 360 \doteq 2.55630250$, so the provided value is fairly accurate, $\log 320 \doteq 2.50514998$, which does indeed round down to $2.5051$, but only barely.  Using just one more significant digit yields $2.52827$.

Comment: Ah, nice.  I didn't think to factorize 337.5.